# What types of plants are Gibberellin used on?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy, growth

On what type of plant (monocot/ eudicot? family? species?) is Gibberellin used on?

I searched through many sources but could not find whether Gibberellin works for all plants or just a specific type or family. I read that it works well for biennials, but what are some of the other plant families that it is useful for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you mean with 'used on' but gibberellins are plant hormones in ferns, monocots and dicots. All of these plants will react to the application of gibberellin but the effect will depend on the dose, type of molecule and tissue where it is applied. All plant hormones have multiple effects but the classic one for gibberellic acid is stem elongation.

Too much of this can kill the plant though as is the case with Bakanae fungus infection which forces the plant to overproduce gibberellic acid which kills it ([reference](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC543401/)).

One common agricultural use is boosting the growth of seedless grapes as the seed is an important site of gibberellin production for maturing fruits.

This [pdf](https://ag.arizona.edu/classes/bio182/Mitch/last%20plant%20lecture%20handout.pdf) gives you a reasonable overview of what gibberellins do

Comment: Your reference link seems to be broken unfortunately.

Comment: @skymningen both links seem to be working for me. One of them is a pdf though, is that the one with the issue?

Comment: No, the reference was not working, now it is. Probably got edited.